# Displaying tiles generated by gdal2tiles with OpenLayers?

Tags: gdal, openlayers, gdal2tiles

I'm currently facing issues displaying tiles generated with gdal2tiles.py in OpenLayers 4.5.6

My geotiff is issued from SHOM catalog.

To generate the tiles, I had to translate my tif to vrt to be a RGB/RGBA compatible file.

```
gdal_translate -of vrt map.tif map_translated.vrt
```

then i've simply run

```
gdal2tiles.py map_translated.vrt
```

and issued a tile map source file like the following

```
<TileMap version="1.0.0" tilemapservice="http://tms.osgeo.org/1.0.0">
  <Title>temp.vrt</Title>
  <Abstract></Abstract>
  <SRS>EPSG:3857</SRS>
  <BoundingBox minx="-3.92503169515670" miny="46.43569348844158" maxx="-1.42506635394127" maxy="47.66245305306844"/>
  <Origin x="-3.92503169515670" y="46.43569348844158"/>
  <TileFormat width="256" height="256" mime-type="image/png" extension="png"/>
  <TileSets profile="mercator">
    <TileSet href="7" units-per-pixel="1222.99245234375007" order="7"/>
    <TileSet href="8" units-per-pixel="611.49622617187504" order="8"/>
    <TileSet href="9" units-per-pixel="305.74811308593752" order="9"/>
    <TileSet href="10" units-per-pixel="152.87405654296876" order="10"/>
    <TileSet href="11" units-per-pixel="76.43702827148438" order="11"/>
    <TileSet href="12" units-per-pixel="38.21851413574219" order="12"/>
  </TileSets>
</TileMap>
```

All samples produced from gdal2tiles are working fine, but i'm trying to integrate tiles to openlayers 4.5.6 with the following code :

```
var mapMinZoom = 7;
var mapMaxZoom = 12;

var mapExtent = [-3.92503169516, 46.4356934884, -1.42506635394, 47.6624530531];
var defaultExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(mapExtent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var mapCenter = [-2.5461600, 47.3793800];
var defaultCenter = ol.proj.fromLonLat(mapCenter);

var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var xyz = new ol.layer.Tile({
  extent: defaultExtent,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    attributions: 'Tiles © SHOM, rendered with ' +
        '<a href="http://www.shom.fr/">Shom</a>',
    url: './data/maps/7068/temp/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    tilePixelRatio: 2,
    minZoom: mapMinZoom,
    maxZoom: mapMaxZoom
  })
});

var view = new ol.View({
  center: defaultCenter,
  zoom: 12
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [ osm, xyz ],
  view: view
});
```

Unfortunatly the map can't find corresponding tiles into the generated tiles folder. Ex :

```
./data/maps/7068/temp/12/2019/1434.png
```

Thing is the zoom and x are fine, but y is not right, my tiles folder got 2xxx.png tiles instead.

I might be missing something about Extent or Translation, should I translate my tiff differently ?

generate my tiles differently ?

Adjust settings on the map ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply change your url to:

```
url: './data/maps/7068/temp/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png',
```

Why?

Because XYZ tiling scheme differs from TMS scheme (produced by gdal2tiles) for tiles.
It's because Y numbering starts at the top for XYZ and at the bottom for TMS (hence the minus sign in suggested url change)

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot ! It's very clear now. I have seen many times this answer with -y before, but i understood it wrong. Was thinking about a complete another use.